# Time tag. What should be inside the tag

Tags: html

I have been searching and I saw different ways to use the time tag. For instance:

```
Last update: <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-15">August 15, 2016</time>

<time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-15">Last update: August 15, 2016</time>
```

I understand that I should use the datetime attribute in a standard way to help machines read it. No doubts about that. But all the information related to time should be inside the tags or only the dates?. In this example, Last update should be inside or outside the time tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/text-level-semantics.html#the-time-element):

> The time element represents its contents, along with a machine-readable form of those contents in the datetime attribute. The kind of content is limited to various kinds of dates, times, time-zone offsets, and durations, as described below.
>
> The datetime attribute may be present. If present, its value must be a representation of the element's contents in a machine-readable format.

`2016-08-15` is the machine readable expression of `August 15, 2016`. It does **not** express the information `Last update:`.

Only the human readable version of the **time** information should be inside the element.

You should be able to use the content of the element and the content of the `datetime` attribute *interchangeably*.

Answer (score 1):

Although the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/time) does not address this question directly, the examples hold **only** the date related info (in a human readable format) inside the `<time>` tag.

Also, according to [this blog post](https://css-tricks.com/time-element/) they point out that although you can put whatever you want inside the tags, it is more common just for it to be a textual human readable representation of what you've got in the datetime attribute.

> It's probably a bit more common for the human-readable version to be just a textual representation of the datetime

Following the examples I would update your markup to:

```
<p>Last update: <time itemprop="dateModified" datetime="2016-08-15">August 15, 2016</time><p>
```